# inserting data into a table while we had selected the primary key of the other table

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the scenario

I have a list of products. when user click on a product it goes to another page which shows the detail of the product.On the product detail page I have a form for reviews for that particular product.Now I have two tables One is for Product detail and the other is for reviews Product detail page have primary key **PID** and reviews table have primary key **RID** also PID is made a foreign key in reviews table.Please someone should tell me how to insert review in the database against that particular product using PID.[image]

Here is the relationship,If there is anything wrong please tell me and suggest me how can I insert data for that particular product

Answer (score 0):

What you want actually is a 1:N relationship with the tables review (1) product (N). Which means the foreigh key goes to the review table. Your table structure is actually correct.

If you want to add a review for a particular product, you simply have to keep the PID where you does the process of adding a review.

If it's not clear, please specify in more detail how you are not able to insert a review in your database.

Cheers,
Olivier

Answer (score 0):

```
// pid of product being reviewed must be included on the review form
// clean review form data
$pid = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $_REQUEST["pid"]);
$name = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-z. -]/i", "", $_REQUEST["name"]);
$comments = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-z.?! -]/i", "", $_REQUEST["comments"]);
$rating = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $_REQUEST["rating"]);

// store review for pid
// assumed pid, rating are integer, name, comment are varchar.
$connhandle = mysqli_connect(...your database...);
$sql = "insert into reviews (pid, name, comment, rating) values ($pid, '$name', '$comments', $rating)";
$r = mysqli_query($connhandle, $sql);
```